# abline does not respect intercepts in R

Tags: r, plot

The following code shows a bizarre behavior of abline: the plotted lines do not reach the specified intercepts. Im using a Rstudio Version 0.98.976. Any hint to avoid this problem?

```
x=seq(1,10)
y=seq(1,10)
m=lm(y~x)
summary(m)
plot(x,y)
abline(1.123e-15, 1.000e+00)
abline(2, 1.000e+00)
abline(3, 1.000e+00)
abline(4, 1.000e+00)
```

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Comment: I see nothing bizarre. Can you post an imagem highlighting the problem?

Comment: set the axis style: `plot(x,y, xaxs = 'i', xlim= c(0,10))` and then look at it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a matter of perspective, since the intercept is simply the value of `y` while `x=0`

```
x=seq(1,10)
y=seq(1,10)
m=lm(y~x)
summary(m)
plot(x,y, ylim = c(0,10), xlim= c(0,10))
abline(1.123e-15, 1)
abline(2, 1.00)
abline(3, 1.00)
abline(4, 1.00)
abline(v=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Consider posting an image of the result.

Comment: Thought the people would prefer a reproducible example they could watch for themselves, now adding a figure.

Comment: I have loaded the image, but I cannot see it, maybe my computer is missing something ...

Comment: It's there. Maybe Ctrl F5 fixes it for you.